# AWS Network Mapping only shows 1 AZ and subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-vpc, subnet, aws-application-load-balancer

I'm trying to create a LB (in EU-Central-1) but it requires at least 2 AZ and 1 subnet mask per AZ. However, there's only 1 AZ that can be selected.

[image]

What should I do to resolve this?

Thank you in advanced! :)

There are quite a lot subnet masks in different regions (eu-west-1, us-east-1) but I could not select those into my mappings. Is there someting wrong with it or I need to create subnet that matches certain conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer. I post here for whoever needs it.

You should have at least 2 subnets in each AZ (eu-west-1, eu-west-0, etc.)

Copy your IPv4 CIDR, eg: 123.xx.16.0/20, and use this [link](https://network00.com/NetworkTools/IPv4AddressPlanner/) to generate subnets depend on your need.

You should be able to copy the newly generated subnets without errors.